# IBM Cognos how to use an equivalent of an absolute cell reference from Excel

Tags: cognos

Hello I am trying to make a report where i have something like

```
+----------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| Account  | Revenue | Budget  | %ofAcct1rev | %ofAcct1budg |
+----------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 |   50000 |   60000 |             |              |
|        2 |      45 |     413 | 45/50000    | 413/60000    |
|        3 |      34 |     234 | 34/50000    | 234/60000    |
|        4 |     234 |     345 | 234/50000   | 345/60000    |
|        5 |      24 |      23 | 24/50000    | 23/60000     |
+----------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

I need to compare the revenue and budget of each row to a specific row.

I have tried using a creating a separate query that filters for only that one account but then I can't seem to reference that new query in my first query.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easy or it could be hard depending on your actual requirement.  If the value you are dividing by is always the largest it could be done via a calc such as:

[Revenue]/maximum([Revenue] for report)

If its truly by row number,  meaning always use row 1,  then you could create a marker column with an if then else construct which zeros out all the other rows so the maximum approach will work.

```
[Marker] would consist of:
 if( running-count([Account])=rownumber)
then ([Revenue])
else (0)
```

Calc would become:

```
[Revenue]/maximum([Marker] for report)
```